# G1GC GC makes use of Swap memory

Tags: java, jvm

The G1GC garbage collector as expected is a hog on memory. However, what is surprising that our applications are holding on the swap memory outside of allocated memory. Do we know if this is expected?

If yes, is there a way to cap the amount of memory allocated from heap to G1 GC.

Comment: That's really a question about your OS. Linux, for example might put stuff into Swap even if there's enough memory, just so that it can quickly free up physical memory if the need arises. Unless you see heavy swap I/O and it impacts your performance, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: yes, it is RedHat. Does it release the swap memory eventually?

Comment: "eventually"? Sure. At the latest when your JVM quits. Otherwise it'll hang on to it unless pressured into releasing it (if swap space gets low, for example). Unused swap space (just like unused memory) is not a useful thing: memory/swap space is only ever useful if it's used. You can tweak how aggressively the kernel puts stuff into swap. That is called "swappiness", google it for details. But be warned that you can easily make performance worse by tweaking it without understanding the whole system.